# JQuery Ajax loaded page, but angular does not work in the partial page in Sails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, sails.js

I use ajax to dynamically load part of page in a Sails project views/homepage.ejs. 
The controller is "food", "show" is one action of "food", so I have a file /views/food/show.ejs.

```
$('#outerDiv').load('food/show');
```

The content of show.ejs is like this:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller("myCtrl",function (){
    this.numInStock= 10;
  })
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>The number in stock is: {{numInStock}}</p>
</div>
```

But the angular in that loaded page still cannot work. 
I'm not sure if this is the right way to implement this functionality. There are others things like customize directives, should I use that?

Comment: can you console.log($compile) ? probably its undefined because you didn't inject this service

Comment: are you trying to nest angular apps?